# Как установить модуль cheerio

Tags: node.js

[image: вот ошибка]
 npm install cheerio не работает.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, то установить его можно только так.

Comment: А вы все правильно настроили до попытки его поставить?

Comment: @VladSpirin что именно, нужно настраивать? (а так хз вроде все ок)

Comment: Судя по ошибке, он не может найти модуль `npm-cli`, это говорит о том, что `nodejs` либо вообще не установлена, либо утановлена с ошибками, либо не прописалась в `PATH` и терминал ее просто не видит. Попробуйте просто переустановить ноду и должно заработать